# Get all the photos from selected album in Photos OSX with applescript

Tags: macos, applescript, photos

I want to create an applescript to display the name of all photos from a selected album in Photos app.
For instance, I select the All Photos album in Photos and then run the script and display the name of all images in the All Photos.

Comment: Do you want to see the photos' file name like IMG1234.jpg?